# c# dynamic invoke method with expression-trees

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression-trees

I am writing a little expression parser and want to include method invocations. 
The syntax would be something like: functionName('stringValue',intValue)

The expression parser should then lookup the static function called "functionName" with the correct signature (in this case string, int)

Parsing the expression is no problem, but I am having troubles invoking the **right** method.

What I've come up with so far is a simple Expression.Call:

```
Expression.Call(typeof(MyContext).GetMethod(functionName), parameterExpressions)
```

This works neatly and can be compiled into an invokable function later.
But it gets tricky when many different overloads, default parameters, params keywords etc come into play. I don't won't to re-implement the whole C# logic of overload resolution and thought the DLR could help me.

with the dynamic keyword I could write:

```
dynamic myC = MyContext;
return myC.functionName(param1, param2);
```

and the DLR would figure out which function overload to call.

The question is, how could I achieve this programmatically?

So far I've had no luck with

```
Expression.Dynamic(..)
```

Comment: Do you know the types of the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload for GetMethod that does the overload resolution for you so long as you know the types.  Similarly, Expression.Call() also has an overload that takes a method name and the types.

```
// Assuming you have parameter expressions with known types...
string functionName = "functionName";
ParameterExpression param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "stringValue");
ParameterExpression param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "intValue");
var parameterExpressions = new ParameterExpression[] { param1, param2};

// Extract the types...
Type[] parameterTypes = parameterExpressions.Select(p => p.Type).ToArray();

// This will do the overload resolution and give you the methodInfo
MethodInfo methodToCall = typeof(Robot).GetMethod(
    functionName,
    parameterTypes);
Expression e = Expression.Call(methodToCall, parameterExpressions);
```

Comment: I do know the parameter types (at run time), so this sounds very promising! Will try that tomorrow

Comment: I was only looking at the GetMethods overloads never at the GetMethod!
Thx for your help

Comment: On closer look, this will only handle overloads, but doesn't offer overload resolution in the presence of e.g. default parameters.

Comment: The overload of `Expression.Call` that takes the array of types does not do overload resolution on the called method - that array is strictly for specifying generic type parameters, if the method is generic. If you want to do overload resolution, you have to go via `GetMethod` (and you can use a custom binder if you want to customize how it works). However, this does not guarantee an exact match with C# overload resolution rule, since the default binder is language-agnostic.

Comment: @PavelMinaev Oh wow, good to know.  I updated the code example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to:

1. Parse your original input (script) string
2. Lex & Map (Functions to Functions & Variables to Dictionary)
3. Execute.

If you can parse out your instructions, as tokenizable strings, then you can execute very specific functionality based on these "strings".

I have just released a [video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnMF9In69aCVjJKg1UmtxXTh4NjTeGK-M) that is probably worth checking out for this purpose.